# ostream operator overloading - inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, ostream

I have a base class called *Item*:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <ostream>

class Item {
public:
    virtual ~Item() {}
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const {}
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, Item& item){
    item.print(out);
    return out;
    }
};



#endif
```

and I have a derived class *Tower*:

```
#ifndef TOWER_H
#define TOWER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include "item.h"
#include "Card.h"

class Tower : public Item {
    unsigned height;
        void print(std::ostream& o) const;
public:
    Tower(const Card& card);
    int demolish(Card& card) const;
    unsigned getHeight() const;
};

#endif
```

Source code for *Tower*:

```
#include "tower.h"



Tower::Tower(const Card& card){
    height = card.getDis();
}

void Tower::print(std::ostream& o) const {
    o << height;
}


int Tower::demolish(Card& card) const{
    try {
    if(height != card.getDis()){
            throw std::exception ();
        } else {
            return height;
        }
    } catch (std::exception e){
        cout<< "Card's value not enough to demolish the tower." << endl;
    }
}

unsigned Tower::getHeight() const {
    return height;
}
```

Now I'm trying to test the code to see if the operator overloading works properly:

```
void test() {
    Card card (Card::SOUTH, 3);
    Tower tower(card);

    std::cout << "Printing tower: " << tower << std::endl;  //PRINTS OUT 3 AS EXPECTED

    Card one (Card::NORTH, 2);
    Card two (Card::WEST, 3);

    std::cout << "Expecting to receive an error: " <<endl;
    tower.demolish(one);

    std::cout << "Expecting to have the tower demolished: ";
    std::cout << tower.demolish(two) <<std::endl;

    std::cout << "Height of the tower: " << tower.getHeight() <<std::endl;

    std::vector<Item> items;       //creating an Item vector
    items.push_back(Tower(one));

    Item items2[1];                //creating an array of Items
    items[0]= tower;

    std::cout << "Printing out an Item: ";    
    std::cout << items.back()<<std::endl;   //EXPECTING TO GET 2 BUT IT PRINTS NOTHING, WHY IS THAT?
    std::cout << "OR: " << items2[0]<<std::endl;  //SAME ISSUE HERE, EXPECTING TO GET 3
}
```

As can be understood from the code, a Card holds an integer value *distance* and an enum value *direction*. It would've been a mess if i included that code too. I have commented my questions in the last piece of code *test()*. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: ¤ `Item items2[1]` creates an array of one `Item` object. When you copy a `Tower` object there, all that's copied is the `Item` base class sub-object. That's called **slicing**. The copy is of the `Item` type. These bits (in your case zero number of bits but that does not matter) don't remember that they were copied from an object of a derived type, and in particular, for the way that almost every C++ implementation works, the *vtable pointer* in the object points to the `Item` class vtable. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<Item> items;       //creating an Item vector
items.push_back(Tower(one));
```

What happens here is called "slicing". Since you're not storing pointers, but actual objects, the `Tower` part of the class is just cut off and only the `Item` part is pushed into the vector. To use virtual functions and polymorphism, you need a reference or pointer to the base class.

```
std::vector<Item*> items;       //creating an Item vector
items.push_back(new Tower(one));
// ...
// at the end of main:
for(int i=0; i < items.size(); ++i)
  delete items[i];
```

Or with smart pointers from Boost or a C++11 library

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<Item>> items;
items.push_back(make_shared<Tower>(one));
// nothing further needs to be done
```

For printing, you now obviously need to dereference the pointer:

```
std::cout << "Printing out an Item: ";    
std::cout << *items.back()<<std::endl;
std::cout << "OR: " << *items2[0]<<std::endl;
```

}

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks very much @Xeo

Comment: @Amino Acid: If this answer solved your problem, you should click the little tick right besides of it. :)